# Strict equality comparison of input value against a number returns false

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

So I have an if statement that is checking the values of a drop down. The user has to select at least one of them to continue. The values are just numbers. My `if` statement checks to see that, basically, the values are equal to zero:

```
if (numChildren === 0 && numAdults === 0){
    Than do this
}
```

But for some reason it keep returning false. I have console logged the numChildren and adults to see what there values are and they are zero I have no idea why it isn't working I have put a "!" before it to cause it to be true but then it remains false. It is a very weird error.

```
$("#Discounts").on("click", function () {
        let numChildren = $("#children").val();
        let numAdults = $("#adults").val();
        console.log("Adults: " + numAdults + "\nChildren: " + numChildren);
        console.log(numChildren === 0 && numAdults === 0);
        if (numChildren === 0 && numAdults === 0) {
            alert("You must select");
            $("#children").val(1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where have you put console.log()s ? try console.log(typeof numChildren)

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird.

You are using the triple equal comparison and, probably, the `numChildren` contains a number in string form (like "0") which you are comparing to `zero` as an actual number.

It should work with:

```
numChildren == 0 && numAdults == 0
```

or

```
Number(numChildren) === 0 && Number(numAdults) === 0
```

This is the official reference: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison

Answer (score 0):

When you use 3 equals in a if statement the `numChildren` must be the same type and value as 0 (integer), not just equal to 0.

Try changing to 2 equals:

```
if (numChildren == 0 && numAdults == 0) {
            alert("You must select");
            $("#children").val(1);
        }
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (Number(numChildren) === 0 && Number(numAdults) === 0) {
        alert("You must select");
        $("#children").val(1);
}
```